# The KafkaConsumer does not read from the offset 0

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to test a Kafka example. I am using Kafka 0.10.0.1
The producer:

```
object ProducerApp extends App {

val topic = "topicTest"
val  props = new Properties()
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "consumer")
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
for(i <- 0 to 20)
{    
val record = new ProducerRecord(topic, "key "+i," value "+i)    
producer.send(record)    
Thread.sleep(100)    
}
}
```

The consumer (the topic "topicTest" is created with 1 partition):

```
object ConsumerApp extends App {
val topic = "topicTest"  
val properties = new Properties
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "consumer")  
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false")  
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
properties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
properties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](properties)  
consumer.subscribe(scala.List(topic).asJava)    
while (true) {
consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment())
val records:ConsumerRecords[String,String] = consumer.poll(20000)
println("records size "+records.count())
records.asScala.foreach(rec => println("offset "+rec.offset()))    
}  
}
```

the problem is that the consumer does not read from the offset 0 at the first iteration but at the other oiterations it does. I want to know the reason and how can I make the consumer reads from the offset 0 at all the iterations.
The expected result is:

```
records size 6
offset 0
offset 1
offset 2
offset 3
offset 4
offset 5
records size 6
offset 0
offset 1
offset 2
offset 3
offset 4
offset 5
...
```

but the obtained result is:

```
records size 4
offset 2
offset 3
offset 4
offset 5
records size 6
offset 0
offset 1
offset 2
offset 3
offset 4
offset 5
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to figure out what is exact mistake, I have written same code as yours. but for me it is working fine. if you want you can use below snippet.

```
import java.util
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRebalanceListener;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer;
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import java.util.Properties

object ConsumerExample extends App {

  val TOPIC = "test-stack"

  val props = new Properties()

  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")


  props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  props.put("group.id", "testinf")
  props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
  props.put("auto.offset.reset.config", "false")

  var listener = new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
    override def onPartitionsAssigned(partitions: util.Collection[TopicPartition]): Unit = {
      println("Assignment : " + partitions)

    }
    override def onPartitionsRevoked(partitions: util.Collection[TopicPartition]): Unit = {
      // do nothing
    }

  }

  val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)

  consumer.subscribe(util.Collections.singletonList(TOPIC), listener)

  while (true) {


    consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment())
    val records = consumer.poll(20000)
    // for (record <- records.asScala) {
    //   println(record)
    // }
    println("records size "+records.count())
    records.asScala.foreach(rec => println("offset "+rec.offset()))  
  }

}
```

Try it out and let me know. if you have any issues.

Comment: thank you but I want that the consumer reads all the records at all the iterations (from the offset 0 to the offset 5). The problem is that it does not read from the offset 0 at the first iteration.

Comment: In the first iteration does it reading always from offset 2 or randomly?

Comment: any idea for my question?

Comment: Give me some clarification, your consumer is 1.  the first iteration from offset 2 and remaining offsets is fine. 2. every iteration randomly. please give confirm it

Comment: I tested the program several times. At the first iteration, the consumer reads randomly from the offset 0 (sometimes from the offset 0, sometimes from the offset 2, sometimes from the offset 1,...). At the other iterations, it reads always from the offset 0.